# Trying to display expression if state exists, getting #Error

Tags: reporting-services

In my SSRS report, I'm trying to display the City and State if the city exists and I'm doing so with this expression

```
=IIF(Fields!Ship_To_City.Value, Fields!Ship_To_City.Value & "," & Fields!Ship_To_State.Value, "")
```

the conditional part of it works, but whenever it's supposed to output the City, State, I get #Error. Any reason why?

Comment: You should check the error message in the Error List when run from Visual Studio to get an idea of the error. Is SHIP TO a Boolean value? If it's 0 and 1 you'd need to change it to check for the INT rather than use it as Boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IIF` conditional goes like this:

```
=IIF(boolean_condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

Now, your `IIF` looks like this:

```
=IIF(Fields!Ship_To_City.Value, Fields!Ship_To_City.Value & "," & Fields!Ship_To_State.Value, "")
```

That is, `Fields!Ship_To_City.Value` is operating as a boolean value in the `boolean_condition` part but then as a string in the `value_if_true` part. One of these isn't going to work.

I assume you want to test that the field isn't null before outputing it, so you want to have an actual boolean condition in your `IIF` like this:

```
=IIF(Fields!Ship_To_City.Value <> Nothing, Fields!Ship_To_City.Value & "," & Fields!Ship_To_State.Value, "")
```